# Is a roll a critical hit if it isn't a natural 20 but modifiers make it a 20?

Tags: dnd-5e, critical-hit

Say for example that a Human Wizard were to cast a Fire Bolt cantrip, and the natural roll was a 17, and with modifiers, a 20. Does that count as a critical hit, after the crit roll?

Answer (score 18):

**No.**

As described [here in the official 5e (basic) rules](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules#howtoplay_1181):

> If the d20 roll for an attack is a 20, the attack hits regardless of any modifiers or the target’s AC. This is called a critical hit, which is explained later in this chapter.