# Would getting a natural 20 with a penalty still count as a critical hit?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, critical-hit, attack-roll

Since rolling a number up to 20 with modifiers (an example 17 + 3) is not counted as a critical hit, what happens in the following case?

If I roll a natural 20 and because of penalties end up with a total of less than 20 (an example 20 - 3) does it still count as a critical hit? Or in this case would it resemble the natural 1 with positive modifiers taking you out of critical error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a roll a critical hit if it isn't a natural 20 but modifiers make it a 20?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96370/is-a-roll-a-critical-hit-if-it-isnt-a-natural-20-but-modifiers-make-it-a-20)

Comment: Hello, @nicodismo and welcome to RPG.SE! Please let us know if the answers at the above linked question also answer your question.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the questions are different, although the existing answer should answer this one too.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Also tangentially related: [Can a Lore bard's Cutting Words feature cancel a critical hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72041/33569), [Can Bardic Inspiration make a roll a Critical Hit?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72065/33569), [Does a natural 20 on the attack roll still automatically hit if the target is wearing adamantine armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133982/33569)

Answer (score 30):

Player's Handbook, page 194:

> ### Rolling 1 or 20
>
> [...] If the d20 roll for an attack is a 20, the attack hits regardless of any modifiers or the target's AC. In addition, the attack is a critical hit, as explained later in this chapter.
>
> If the d20 roll for an attack is a 1, the attack misses regardless of any modifiers or the target's AC.

Pretty clear, right? If the die says 20, it's a hit and a crit, and I don't care if you have a -38 on the roll. And if you roll an 17 and add +7 to it, you didn't roll a crit even though your total was above 20.  Only the number on the die matters.

As to your last line, I'm not sure what you mean about a "natural 1 with positive modifiers". As you can see by the above rule, a natural 1 is a miss no matter what bonuses you could apply to it (unless you have advantage, or some other way to roll again and use the number on the new die instead). D&D 5th Edition does not have any "critical miss/failure/error" rules, so those would be entirely homebrewed by your DM and I can't make any comment on how those would operate.

That said, there's a strong argument for *not* having critical miss rules. The higher number of attack rolls per turn from highly skilled characters means they'll roll critical misses *more often* than a low level character would, which seems rather silly.

Comment: I have critical misses in my game; they're only applicable to the first attack in a sequence (for a character with multiple attacks). So the current last paragraph is maybe not a strong argument/not needed for this answer.

Comment: “D&D 5th Edition does not have any ‘critical miss/failure/error rules” — are you referencing something separate from the second paragraph in your PHB quote? That quote seems to directly state a critical miss rule.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Critical miss is not the same as an automatic miss with a natural 1, it's the thing otherwise known as a "fumble" rule, where something ridiculously awful happens when you roll a 1 on an attack, like you break your weapon, fall down, or stab yourself.

Answer (score 6):

## If you roll a 20, it counts as a critical hit, regardless of modifiers

> If the d20 roll for an attack is a 20, the attack hits regardless of any modifiers or the target’s AC. This is called a critical hit, which is explained later in this chapter. (PHB 194)

All that matters is the number you roll on the d20. If that number is a 20, it is a critical hit, no matter what modifiers you would have normally had to the roll. If you roll a 20 and have a -50 modifier to the attack, it still counts as a critical hit.

To be clear, you only get a critical hit if you roll a 20 on a d20. If your roll is not a 20 then you don't have a critical hit, even if your bonuses would make the total attack 20 (or more).

The case of rolling a 1 is the same:

> If the d20 roll for an attack is a 1, the attack misses regardless of any modifiers or the target's AC. (PHB 194)

So if you roll a 1, your attack misses, no matter what bonuses you had to the attack. Do note that D&D5e has no "critical error" rules by default beyond attacks missing when a 1 is rolled.